# Continuous Probability Density Function: question on definition

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have seen this with multiple definitions.  It also appears the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus applies.  Does anyone know the correct definition?  I think my confusion is between $\le$ and $=$. I list some definitions below to show my confusion.

$f_X(z) = \frac {d F_{\le X}(z)} {dz}$, $f_X : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ is the PDF and $F_{\le X} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ is the CDF.

[Wiki definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function):

a)
$$
P(a \le X \le b) = \int_a^b f_X(z) \, dz = F_{\le X}(b) - F_{\le X}(a)
$$

I think this should really be two different CDFs, $\le$ and $\lt$ as follows.  Otherwise the value at $a$ is excluded.:

b)
$$
P(a \le X \le b) = \int_a^b f_X(z) \, dz = F_{\le X}(b) - F_{\lt X}(a)
$$

this definition is from my notes (which I think is the correct one):

c)
$$
P(a \lt X \le b) = \int_a^b f_X(z) \, dz = F_{\le X}(b) - F_{\le X}(a)
$$

I think whats confusing me is application of the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).  It doesn't agree with equality in form (c) above:

d)
$$
\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a)
$$

Comment: I have taken probability, but the integral of the density function I have seen looks like: $$P(a \leq X \leq b) = \int_a^b f_X(z) dz = F_{X}(b) - F_{X}(a)$$ where $F_X(z)$ is the CDF and $F_{X}(b) - F_{X}(a)$ is the CDF evaluated at the integration bounds given by the PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all equivalent. I will illustrate by showing that a) gives c): If $f_X$ is an integrable function and, $$P(a \leq X \leq b)=\int_a^b f_X(x)\,dx$$ then we can put $a=b$ to see that for all $a$,$$P(X=a)=\int_a^a f_X(x) \, dx=0$$Therefore, $$P(a<x\leq b)=P(a\leq X \leq b)-P(X=a)=\int_a^b f_X(x) \, dx$$